# Modify user input to use in exec call

Tags: c, string, token, exec, user-input

I am trying to modify a user input string to call execvp in a future function. In my code I have a function which tokenises the user input such that if the user entered in: command a b c. It outputs `char** output = { "command", "a", "b", "c", NULL }` The length of the user input is unknown.
My issue is that I want to modify the variable char** output to remove the user entered command, such that I get `char** output = {"a", "b", "c", NULL }`
My current attempt at this is in the code below:

```
char** exec_arg(char** output, int numTokens){
143     char* argExec[numTokens];
147     for(int k = 0; k < (numTokens-1); k++){
148         argExec[k] = output[k+1];
149         printf("%s", argExec[k]);
150     }
152     return argExec;
155 }
```

However I am finding that when I run this I am getting the output: {"a", "b", "c"}

Comment: You are returning the reference of a local variable that does not "live" after returning.

Comment: How do I go about ensuring it does "live" after returning? I want to avoid global variables. do I add it to a struct?